# Roll-Forward Date Patterns in Excel

Tags: excel-2010

Using Excel 2010, I need to take an existing date in 2015 (i.e. 2/11/15), and calculate the same date position in the next year.  In other words, whatever is the specific date pattern with the existing date, I'm looking for a formula that will help me calculate the exact same date pattern.  If 2/11/15 is the second Wednesday in February of 2015, I need a formula to help me calculate (using the existing date) the second Wednesday of February in 2016.

Comment: Nov-2015 has 5 Sundays and 5 Mondays. Nov-2016 has 5 Tuesdays and 5 Wednesdays but neither 5 Sundays nor 5 Mondays.

Comment: Are you asserting that Excel cannot interpret future calendar conditions.

Comment: My intention was to imply that your logic as stated could not always be followed and that must be accounted for. In the specific case above, you might have to say *the last Sunday in Nov* rather than the *5th Sunday in Nov*. If you are looking for a formula that will retrieve a date in the future, these anomalies need to be addressed and alternative conditions stated when the first set of conditions cannot be met. If you are simply trying to predict what day that some holidays or observances will arrive on next year, then these should have been specified since formulas for most already exist.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks for your reply. You're correct - there's many "conditions" to account for.  Two colleagues helped-out with the following:  

=IF('Data (Reference)'!C14>"", CONCATENATE(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14, "MM"),"/", TEXT(7-(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14,"MM"),"/", Input!$C$2))-1)-7+TEXT(WEEKDAY('Data (Reference)'!C14), "DD")+(CEILING(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14, "DD")/7, 1)-(IF(TEXT(WEEKDAY('Data (Reference)'!C14), "DD")<TEXT(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14,"MM"),"/", Input!$C$2)), "DD"), 0, 1)))*7, "DD"),"/",Input!$C$2), "")

Answer (score 0):

@Jeeped, thanks for your reply. You're correct - there's many "conditions" to account for.  Two colleagues helped-out with the following:

=IF('Data (Reference)'!C14>"", CONCATENATE(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14, "MM"),"/", TEXT(7-(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14,"MM"),"/", Input!$C$2))-1)-7+TEXT(WEEKDAY('Data (Reference)'!C14), "DD")+(CEILING(TEXT('Data (Reference)'!C14, "DD")/7, 1)-(IF(TEXT(WEEKDAY('Data (Reference)'!C14), "DD")

We had to consider wherever the existing date fell, and dynamically identify the pattern and/or condition and re-apply it in the roll-forward sequence.